# Why there is no autocomplete from Intellisens?

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

Trying a C++ example with VS 2017 and Unreal I saw in the video once the instructor type `->GetF` the intellisense appear but with me it does not so why is that ? I am getting also a red line error under the word `GetWorld()` "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed" but the code compile fine !!

```
void UOpenDoor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    ActorThatOpen = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPawn();

}
```

Comment: In main menu, click Project -> Rescan solution

Comment: thanks but did not work !

Comment: Did you install the engine with the source files? Visual Studio needs to be able to scan them to build the intellisense db.
I personally use the Visual Assist plugin (https://www.wholetomato.com/) as it also adds much better code coloring and Intellisense options.

Comment: I found that I installed source code

Comment: @TheBrain Tomato solved my problem thanks alot